# Why can't I add comments to my own question's answer on Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, comments

I know I can post a comment on the answers to my own questions without needing 50 reputation, but I don't see it showing up after adding the comment, what might be the reason?

Comment: Do you see any errors in your browser's console?

Comment: some problem with chrome i guess, shows "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'create' of undefined " .

Comment: It sounds like a scripting error. As far as I'm aware, there is no restriction that says you can't do this.

Comment: Funny, your comments are working just fine here ;)

Comment: yes it's working because I'm Adding comments with firefox now.

Comment: I had this problem once, all I did was update to the latest chrome and it worked. I didn't know about any error messages, so I don't know if that error message you get is directly related to your issue.

Comment: Which browser extensions do you have on Chrome? Adblock?

Answer (score 3):

I have had this problem too for a while (for more than a month). It occurred only in Chrome on Ubuntu, version 12.04 / 11.04. Chrome is latest version (for Ubuntu 12.04 version 35.0.1916.153). Comments works well in FF / Opera on Ubuntu, and comments works well in Chrome on windows.

The errors I got in the console was :

```
Uncaught QuotaExceededError: Failed to execute 'setItem' on 'Storage': Setting the value of 'records._index_' exceeded the quota. lawnchair.js:188
Uncaught QuotaExceededError: Failed to set the 'gps-pending' property on 'Storage': Setting the value of 'gps-pending' exceeded the quota.
```

**Solution (at least it worked for me)** :
Go clear the browser cache. The LocalStorage is full - it just have to be emptied. Then you will be able to post comments again :)

Comment: that was a simple typo, I meant to write "Uuuuubuuuuntuuuuu" :)